# This is one of the most entertaining movies that has/have appeared this year

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> This is one of the most entertaining movies that **has/have** appeared this year.

Can't figure out with certainty whether the subject is singular or plural. Seems like **has** is the obvious answer but presence of ***that*** is making me falter.

Comment: ...native speakers use both versions (they're both syntactically fine), but in constructions of the general form *one of NOUN who/that VERB*, [the plural verb is far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+of+those+who+believes%2Cone+of+those+who+believe&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20those%20who%20believes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20those%20who%20believe%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20those%20who%20believes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20those%20who%20believe%3B%2Cc0) (***have***, in your example).

Comment: *One of my marbles **is** broken.* The subject of the sentence is a single marble, so the singular verb is used. But in the example sentence, the subject is *the most entertaining movies* (plural)—it's talking abut a plural subject, so it needs a plural verb. *This is one of* **(the most entertaining movies that have appeared this year)**.